# lining up data in console output java

Tags: java, alignment, output

I have the following extract of code below;

The issue is that

```
(element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue())
```

has output of a differing number of characters

which then causes `eventy` to be moved out of line with other output from the other rows therefore giving a zig zag appearance of data instead of data in columns, i have tried experimenting with tabs and spaces. But would appreciate some help please.

```
String eventy = null;

for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
    Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
    String nodeName = element.getNodeName();

    switch (nodeName) {
        case "assd":
            System.out.println((element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()) + "\t  " eventy);
            break;
        case "eventy":
            eventy = element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assume maximum length of strings from "assd" child node, you could use [`System.out.printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). For example:

```
System.out.printf("%-20s   %s%n", element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue(), eventy)
```

would print a value of "assd" child node to first column with width 20 then value of variable `eventy` and then new line separator.

See [Format String Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: This works perfectly i dont understand why instead of + eventy it now changes to ,eventy?

Comment: similarly if i had another variable called eventyo how would i add that to the output?

Comment: worked it out excellent System.out.printf("%-30s   %-30s    %s%n", element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue(), eventy,eventyo);