# putting data into array and then JTable

Tags: java, arrays, jtable

Referring to an earlier question i asked

[lining up data in console output java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903850/lining-up-data-in-console-output-java)

I wish to put my output in an array so that i can then further put this into a JTable

The extract for my code so far is, i am currently printing out the output to the console.

```
String assd = null;
String eventy = null;
String assdFT = null;


for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
String nodeName = element.getNodeName();

switch (nodeName) {
case "assd":
assd = element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();


break;
case "eventy":
eventy = element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue(); 

break;
case "assdFT":

assdFT = element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue(); 
break;

System.out.printf("%-30s  %-20s  %s%n", assd,  eventy,assdFT);




Object[][] data = {{assd,  eventy,assdFT}};//this only appears to put the elements in row 1, since System.out.println(data[1][0]) causes an out of array exception but System.out.println(data[0][0]) prints out all the elements of assd
```

Comment: This code is horrible, please format and indent your code, there are braces that are missing and the `switch` is just a mess. :)!

Comment: i have now improved the appearance of the code

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) - Have a look at the `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: I can't see how you code could actually print anything.  How do you know when to actually print a line?

Comment: @ MadProgrammer the code looks through an XML schema and finds the item and prints it

Answer (score 0):

To put data directly into a JTable pass an instance of your custom AbstractTableModel to the JTable constructor. Within TableModel, you can define what data is displayed and how it is accessed.

It would probably look something like this:

```
public class HeaderTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8974549762036798969L;

private Object[][] myData;

public HeaderTableModel(final Object[][] theRows) {
    myHeaderRows = theRows;
}


/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see javax.swing.table.TableModel#getColumnCount()
 */
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return LocalStorage.getNumColumns();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see javax.swing.table.TableModel#getRowCount()
 */
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return LocalStorage.getNumRows();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see javax.swing.table.TableModel#getValueAt(int, int)
 */
@Override
public Object getValueAt(final int theRow, final int theColumn) {
    return myHeaderRows[theRow][theColumn];
}
```

Comment: but how do i get each element assd,  eventy, assdFT into the table? I am just a novice

Comment: you pass them in part of your data into the table model.

Comment: okay, do i need this part of the code to create the array?                 Object[][] data = new Object[1000][10];    
for (int r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
for (int c=0; c<data[r].length; c++) {
 data[r][c]=assd;//your value
}}

Comment: @Mr. Assistance, if that's the data you wanna display, then yes

Comment: but the problem with my array is that i am only adding assd, how do i build it to add all three elements assd,  eventy,assdFT ?

Comment: that all depends on what you want to achieve. I took from your question what I could easily discern and answer it. you might be better served by rewriting your question with clearer objectives.

Comment: well my understanding of Jtables from web references is that i create an array of items and then the array is put into a table. From web references the  typical example is Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
};

Comment: if i did something like Object[][] data = {assd,eventy,assdFT} then i think all i would be doing is adding the data to row 1 as it loops, rather than filling down the rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86934/discussion-between-andrewdleach-and-mr-assistance).